# Python - matplotlib - PyQT: Copy image to clipboard

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I want to copy the current figure of matplotlib to the clipboard:

this code doens't work(for testing purposes, I want to save the bitmap to disk later on I will use it as a bitmap-image. I want to start with having a memory-bitmap that I can use with the QT's QImage, QPixmap, QBitmap or some other QT-class).

```
rgba = self.canvas.buffer_rgba()
im = QImage(self.canvas.buffer_rgba())
print(im.depth())   # --> 0
print(im.save('test.gif',r'GIF')) # ---> False
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not creating a valid image.

```
im = QImage(self.canvas.buffer_rgba())
```

actually ignores the argument you're passing. `canvas.buffer_rgba()` returns a memoryview, which none of the [available constructors](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qimage.html) can work with:

```
QImage()
QImage(QSize, QImage.Format)
QImage(int, int, QImage.Format)
QImage(str, int, int, QImage.Format)
QImage(sip.voidptr, int, int, QImage.Format)
QImage(str, int, int, int, QImage.Format)
QImage(sip.voidptr, int, int, int, QImage.Format)
QImage(list-of-str)
QImage(QString, str format=None)
QImage(QImage)
QImage(QVariant)
```

In python there is really only one `__init__` method, so type checking has to be done by internal checks. `QImage(QVariant)` is basically the same as `QImage(object)` (in fact, in python3, that's *exactly* what it is), so it basically allows you to pass any object, it's just ignored if it can't be converted to a `QVariant` internally, so the returned QImage will be empty.

If you want to construct a image from raw rgba data, you need to specify it's size, as there is no way to get this information from raw data, and also the format. This should work:

```
size = self.canvas.size()
width, height = size.width(), size.height()
im = QImage(self.canvas.buffer_rgba(), width, height, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
im.save('test.png')
```

Another way would be to grab the canvas directly as a pixmap:

```
pixmap = QPixmap.grabWidget(self.canvas)
pixmap.save('test.png')
```

Save to clipboard:

```
QApplication.clipboard().setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Oh, and you shouldn't use `gif`, use `png`. Due to it's proprietary nature `gif` is usually not available as supported output format. Check `QImageWriter.supportedImageFormats()`.

Comment: Thanks, it works!
The only thing that bothers me now is that the graph-colors are changed back to default colors in the saved image-file, while on screen there are different as desired.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @mata answer, for the update, since QPixmap.grabWidget is now obsolete, we can use:

```
pixmap = self.canvas.grab()
QApplication.clipboard().setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: I really appreciat your simple solution for this problem. This really works for me.

Answer (score 0):

when working in an interactive Python shell you can use a function like this

```
def to_clipboard(fig):
  QApplication.clipboard().setImage(QPixmap.grabWidget(fig.canvas).toImage())
  print('figure %d copied to clipboard' % fig.number)
```

and then use it like `to_clipboard(gcf())` to store the current figure.