# Python - matplotlib - PyQT: plot to QPixmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqt

I want to visualise matplotlibs colormaps (similar to http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) and use it as QPixmaps in PyQt widgets. The idea is to create the plots in matplotlib without actually showing it (or saving it to a file) and convert it to a QPixmap. The solution offered here ([Python - matplotlib - PyQT: Copy image to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676373/python-matplotlib-pyqt-copy-image-to-clipboard)) doesn't seem to work, maybe because I don't want to show the matplotlib plot.

Comment: You should your code for context - the answer to the question you linked should work fine and does not require showing the matplotlib plot at all, so you should clarify what you mean by "doesn't work."

Comment: After I grabbed the pixmap it had size 0x0

Comment: Eventually, I went another way: instead of creating the gradient with matplotlib, I used the setPixel method of QImage

Comment: This is _exactly_ what the QtAgg backend does.  If you really do not want to use the QT widgets mpl ships, use the `Agg` backend and get the raw RGBA buffer.  See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py#L88 for how we do it internally.

Comment: @tcaswell I'm sure you know a lot about the raw RGBA buffer, I don't. The only reference I could find on matplotlib.org was here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/agg_buffer_to_array.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried the following and that works:

```
def testColourMap(cmap):
    sp = SubplotParams(left=0., bottom=0., right=1., top=1.)
    fig = Figure((2.5,.2), subplotpars = sp)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    gradient = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)
    gradient = np.vstack((gradient, gradient))
    ax.imshow(gradient, aspect=10, cmap=cmap)
    ax.set_axis_off()
    canvas.draw()
    size = canvas.size()
    width, height = size.width(), size.height()
    im = QImage(canvas.buffer_rgba(), width, height, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    return QPixmap(im)
```

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib has support for PySide via a backend (see for example [this tutorial](https://www.mfitzp.com/tutorials/pyside-plotting-matplotlib/)), but not for the new PySide6 yet, so I ran into a similar problem.

Based in part on Michael's answer above, I found the following minimal example to work with PySide6 6.1.0 and matplotlib 3.4.2:

```py
from PySide6.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def get_q_pixmap():
    fig = Figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot([1, 2, 4, 3])
    ax.set_title('test plot')
    canvas.draw()
    
    width, height = fig.figbbox.width, fig.figbbox.height
    img = QImage(canvas.buffer_rgba(), width, height, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    pixmap = QPixmap(img)
    return pixmap
```

Somewhat counter-intuitive for me, the easiest way to display this `QPixmap` seems to be using the `setPixmap()` method of a `QLabel`.