# How to keep PyQt GUI responsive when blocking tasks are GUI related?

Tags: multithreading, qt, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm writing an app that embeds a bunch of `matplotlib` figures into a `PyQt` GUI. The updating of these figures can take up to a few seconds, so I would like to introduce a waiting indicator to display while the plots are being drawn. I've moved all the data processing code into its own thread, but it seems the actual plotting calls are often making up the majority of processing time.

I have written a waiting indicator that uses a `QTimer` instance to trigger `paintEvent` on the widget. This works just fine when all the intensive processing can be pushed into another thread. The problem is that these calls to construct the `matplotlib` plots cannot be moved outside of the main thread due to the way `Qt` is designed, and so block the updating of the waiting indicator, rendering it kind of useless.

I've introduced some calls to `QCoreApplication.processEvents()` after the updating of each figure, which improves the performance a little. I've also toyed with the idea of monkeypatching a bunch of methods of `matplotlib.axes.Axes` to include calls to `QCoreApplication.processEvents()`, but I can see that getting messy. Is this the best I can do? Is there any way to interrupt the main thread at regular intervals and force it to process new events?

Comment: I don't know of a direct way around this. The only thing I can think of is to reduce your plotting time. It seems likely that you are trying to plot more data than can be viewed with the resolution of your screen. You could down sample your data in a thread, and then plot from the main thread. The down sampling could be triggered on zoom so that you always match the amount of data to the current display. I've done this before with pyqtgraph (which I thought was slightly faster than matplotlib)

Comment: I suspect you might be correct for some of the figures. I'll try your suggestion and see if I can make some gains. However, I think it's only part of the problem. The number of figures appears to make more of a difference than the size of the data.

Comment: Yeah matplotlib is not very lean, especially if you use something like imshow. I'm not sure how many figures you have but I've done ~20 with the down sampling trick in pyqtgraph (all x-axes were linked together). But I'm sure it's highly dependent on the data!

Answer (score 1):

It should also help a big deal to do the actual drawing on a `QPixmap` in a thread. Drawing that pixmap with QPainters `drawPixmap()` method is very fast. And you need to recreate the pixmap only when really needed (e.g. after Zooming or so). In the meantime you just have to reuse that already drawn pixmap. The actual paintEvents using `drawPixmap()` will cost close to nothing and your GUI will be completely responsive.

Clobbering the code with `processEvent()` is not only ugly but can cause very nasty and very hard to debug malfunctions. E.g. it might cause premature deletion of objects which are still in use but were scheduled for deletion using `deleteLater()`.

This Answer might be also of use: [Python - matplotlib - PyQT: plot to QPixmap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30646152/3021018)

I havn't used matplotlib, yet. But **in case it uses directly QWidgets and can not be used without** it won't be so easy as you mentioned above. But you could do the drawing in another process started by your GUI which uses matplotlib as in the link above and stores the pixmap to disk and your gui loads whenever a new pixmap is ready. `QFileSystemWatcher` might help here to avoid polling.